# How can the value of y-axis be printed along with the line formed in gnuplot?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have used the following commands and obtained a graph as given below.

```
gnuplot> set xlabel "Input (N)"
gnuplot> set xrange [0:590]
gnuplot> set ylabel "Time (secs)"
gnuplot> set yrange [0:0.5]
gnuplot> set title "MATRIX ADDITION-Sequential VS Parallel program run in Cluster"
gnuplot> set for [i=0:24] xtics (0,25*i)
gnuplot> plot 'madd.csv' using 1:2 with lines title "Sequential Program" \
        lc rgb "blue" lw 4, 'madd_spp.csv' using 1:3 with lines \
        title "Parallel Program " lc rgb "green" lw 4
```

[image: Gnuplot output]

Now I need to print the value of y-axis in the lines obtained after plotting using gnuplot. How will I do that?

Comment: Just cleaned up `i` -> `I` for your.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gnuplot's [labels](http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/labels.html) style:

```
plot 'madd.csv' using 1:2 with lines title "Sequential Program" \
lc rgb "blue" lw 4, '' using 1:2:2 with labels tc rgb "blue" notitle, \
'madd_spp.csv' using 1:3 with lines title "Parallel Program " \
lc rgb "green" lw 4, '' using 1:3:3 with labels tc rgb "green" notitle
```

If the labels bump into your lines too much, you can give them an offset:

```
plot 'madd.csv' using 1:2 with lines title "Sequential Program" \
lc rgb "blue" lw 4, '' using 1:2:2 with labels tc rgb "blue" notitle, \
'madd_spp.csv' using 1:3 with lines title "Parallel Program " \
lc rgb "green" lw 4, '' using 1:3:3 with labels tc rgb "green" offset 2 notitle
```

Comment: Took the liberty of shortening the lines.